# sonarqube and sonarlint have diferent number of issues

Tags: sonarqube

I am running the latest SonarQube version (9.7.1.62043) and latest sonarlint version (7.2.1) in JetBrains IntelliJ. I have connected the SonarQube instance and add the project key of the project. In the same branch the findings are different in some times the sonarlint plugin finds more issues and in some times finds fewer issues. Although I have checked some specific files and it's the same finding.
Has anyone here the same problem ???
Is there any explanation ???

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here that because it uses generic rules if custom rules has been applied to the SonarQube server, then the result may defer so there isn't a good solution here.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).